# Pull All image from a folder in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress plugin and in that plugin i need to pull all image with .png extention from a folder which reside my plugin images folder. I am using the following code

```
foreach ( glob( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ) .'images/previews/*.png') as $img ) { echo $img.'<br>';
     echo '<img src="$img" alt="">';
    }
```

when i echo the $img it shows the entire path but when i use this path as the image source it doesnot show the image.It shows a broken image if i dont use the 'alt'. I have searched for it but cant find any solution on web which is working for me. But a raw php file with the same code is working just fine

Comment: I'm not that familia with PHP, but wouldn't the second echo always echo the following `<img src="$img" alt="">`?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code and look at the source of your page you'll see that you aren't actually putting the value of `$img` into your `img` tag.

```
echo '<img src="$img" alt="">'; // this is what you have now

echo '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="">'; // this is what you need
```

Edit 10/13/2015 2:52 PM CST: Here is a link to some php code using my above example with the comment this is what you need. It generates a good `img` tag that if placed in an HTML file and rendered by a browser would show an image on the screen. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7dbe3e475ac83c8eeaa1ac6efb08063a889d6ca

If it's not working make sure you can actually browse (with your browser) to the content inside the `src` tag.

Comment: Sorry I already tried it before but the result is same #edhedges

Comment: @BashartheCoder I'll post an runnable example in a few, but the second line is rendering an image for me correctly.

Comment: I think you cant understand my problem i said this code work in a single php file but when i use the same coding convention in my plugin it dont work it shows broken image

Comment: @BashartheCoder What's the value of just one `@img`? Instead of an empty `alt` property give it a bogus value. Maybe "test". If your image is broken it could be that the value of the `src` attribute doesn't actually point to an image.

Comment: yah the src is not pointing to the actual location but if i echo the $img it shows the entire path corectly

Comment: @BashartheCoder I don't see how that can be true and without a runnable example I can't really help you any more. The only tips I have are make sure that the value of `$img` actually points to a location on the server where the `img` element is being rendered and make sure that you have concatenated the string correctly by using a `.` on either side of the `@img` variable.